# Converting delimited values into a comma separated list

Tags: mysql, sql

My Webapp (PHP/jQuery/MySQL) has features which enable me to send out nicely formatted html email notifications to my customers based on certain events.  The code works nicely and merges data from my Database into form fields although I need to enhance it to be able to provide enriched/localised/reformatted data in some circumstances.

For example:
-  Provide date/time values in a user's own timezone
-  Provide monetary values formatted to a user's locale

This requires me to do another pass of the email content to detect whether any fields remain unmerged before sending the email off to the user and if so, to format those field values appropriately before sending the email.  Therefore what I want to do is extract a list of all delimited fieldnames from a table field value and return that list in comma delimited form.

- I can already count how many times a delimeter appears
- I can also find the position of the first delimeter
- It looks like it would be easy to split the values if I was using the same opening and closing delimeters but because I have many email templates already in use, this isn't currently viable

I don't have any code for this yet.  I'm just trying to avoid writing my own MySQL function to do this, by using existing MySQL functions if they are capable of doing this.

I've tried using various combinations of SUBSTRING, SUBSTRING_INDEX, LOCATE.

So what I need to be able to do is something like this:

```
SELECT msg_id, values_found_between(msg_content,"<",">") AS comma_delimited_list;
```

So for example, with source data of...

```
msg_id | msg_content
-------+------------
1      | The quick brown <fox> jumps over the lazy <dog>
2      | The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog
```

I can get a resulting recordset such as this:

```
msg_id | comma_seperated_list
-------+------------
1      | fox,dog
```

Alright, I had a crack and this seems to work well:

```
CREATE FUNCTION db.`FN_find_values_between`(`in_haystack` VARCHAR(10000), `in_opening_delimiter` VARCHAR(1),`in_closing_delimiter` VARCHAR(1)) RETURNS varchar(1000) CHARSET utf8
BEGIN

  DECLARE numFoundOpen INT DEFAULT 0;
  DECLARE numFoundClose INT DEFAULT 0;
  DECLARE numFoundTarget INT DEFAULT 0;
  DECLARE numCurrentIndex INT DEFAULT 0;
  DECLARE strOutput VARCHAR(1000) DEFAULT "";
  DECLARE numSearchFromPos INT DEFAULT 1;
  DECLARE numCurrentCharPosStart INT DEFAULT 1;
  DECLARE numCurrentCharPosEnd INT DEFAULT 1;
  DECLARE strCurrentFieldname VARCHAR(50) DEFAULT "";
  DECLARE numLength INT DEFAULT 0;

  SET numFoundOpen=
  (SELECT   
    ROUND ((LENGTH(in_haystack)- LENGTH( REPLACE (in_haystack, in_opening_delimiter, ""))) / LENGTH(in_opening_delimiter)));

  SET numFoundClose=
  (SELECT   
  ROUND ((LENGTH(in_haystack)- LENGTH( REPLACE (in_haystack, in_closing_delimiter, ""))) / LENGTH(in_closing_delimiter)));
  IF (numFoundOpen=numFoundClose) THEN
    SET numFoundTarget=numFoundOpen;
  END IF;

  WHILE numCurrentIndex < numFoundTarget DO
    SET numCurrentIndex=numCurrentIndex+1;
    SET numCurrentCharPosStart = LOCATE(in_opening_delimiter, in_haystack, numSearchFromPos);
    SET numCurrentCharPosEnd   = LOCATE(in_closing_delimiter, in_haystack, numSearchFromPos);
    SET numLength=1+(numCurrentCharPosEnd-numCurrentCharPosStart);
    SET strCurrentFieldname=SUBSTRING(in_haystack,numCurrentCharPosStart,numLength);
    SET strOutput=CONCAT(strOutput,strCurrentFieldname,",");
    SET strCurrentFieldname="";
    SET numSearchFromPos=numCurrentCharPosEnd+1;
  END WHILE;
  IF (strOutput <> "") THEN
    SET strOutput=LEFT(strOutput,LENGTH(strOutput)-1);
  END IF;
  RETURN strOutput;
END;
```

Comment: What version of MySQL are you using?

Comment: comma_separated_lists will cause you pain. Suggest fixing that first. Single value per row/column is a good key to DB design.

Comment: The reason I need a comma separated list is that I need to return the values back to PHP and it's alot quicker to return a CSV list which I can then convert to an array and begin populating, rather than manually iterating through a recordset to manipulate the values from PHP.  Btw I'm using MySQL version is 5.7.25-0ubuntu0.18.04.2.

Comment: I had a crack at writing the function and it seems to work well so I've shared the code above in case it's handy for anyone else.  It doesn't strip the delimiters from the resulting fields in the CSV list but that's easy to do.

Answer (score 0):

As per the code above, I managed to write my own MySQL function to do this.